# How to provide authenticated iCal feed from salesforce to any other calendar application?

Tags: force.com, integration, apexrest, public-calendar

I wanted to publish an ics file as an iCal feed from  salesforce which can be consumed by any calendaring application supporting internet calendar feature. Currently i have exposed this ics file from my org using force.com site and using REST api, but its unauthenticated. Is there any way to publish ics file which will authenticate user at the time of putting iCal URL in their calendar?

Comment: Does your site have a certificate? I'd expect you'd need a CA Certificate for your site as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe so, although I'd be happy for someone to prove me wrong.

A Force.com site doesn't have support for Basic URL Authentication.

It might be easiest to go with a URL obfuscation scheme and then verify it in the Apex code. You could require a URL parameter that will be matched against a custom field on the User record. As crmprogdev commented, then take steps to ensure that the URL doesn't leak out, such as [only using HTTPS](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_login_and_registration_settings.htm).